# Unity Android: How to preload scenes in cache

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

When I load scenes the first time after app installation on my android phone, it takes time I.e. few seconds. Thereafter all the scenes load pretty fast. I am assuming the faster load times is because the scenes are loaded from cache.
So how can I preload all the scenes in cache or at least the 'heavy' scenes so that they get loaded fast even the first time?

Thanks.

Comment: Is it first time only or does it happen any time you re-open the app after killing it (mean the process is destroyed, not the app is in the background)?

Comment: Are you using the Resources folder?

Comment: It is only first time after installation that it loads slow. Even when i kill the app and relaunch it the loading is fast until I reinstall the app or clear app data through settings.

Comment: Yes I am using Resources folder for level configuration not for data.

Comment: I can't tell what's wrong.. I've seen this problem on this site before and can't tell it there was a solution. What's your Unity version? Can you update it and see what happens?

Comment: I don't think it's Unity problem. I am using 5.5.4 which isn't that old. I think I I will just try to further optimize the slow loading scene. Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't matter of old or new in your case. What matters is the version this problem is found in. It's just that 5.5.4 is the-same version I saw this exact type of problem on. This is likely a bug and I think the only way out is to update but you are free to do whatever you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is you can't, the first time your app runs it will create [its own cache](https://en.droidwiki.org/wiki/Dalvik-cache) and that takes time, But you can create a loading screen and load your scenes asynchronously, there are a lot of tutorials about that

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync.html

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class Example : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Update()
    {
        //Press the space key to start coroutine
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            //Use a coroutine to load the Scene in the background
            StartCoroutine(LoadYourAsyncScene());
        }
    }

    IEnumerator LoadYourAsyncScene()
    {
        // The Application loads the Scene in the background at the same time as the current Scene.
        //This is particularly good for creating loading screens. You could also load the Scene by build //number.
        AsyncOperation asyncLoad = SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync("Scene2");

        //Wait until the last operation fully loads to return anything
        while (!asyncLoad.isDone)
        {
            yield return null;
        }
    }
}
```

http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/make-loading-screen-unity

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YMj2qPq9CP8

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalvik_%28software%29

Comment: Thanks. I will try it.